# Using preg_replace to reformat bbcode

Tags: php, regex

I am making forum from phpbb to php native and I need to parse some bbcode tags with uid inside. This is the code to parse it into regular bbcode without the uid:

```
$regex = "#\[quote:(.*)=(.*)\](.+)\[/quote:(.+)\]#isU";
$text = "outside sample
[quote:c1891a7ad3]
text with link https://www.facebook.com/groups/35688476100/?fref=ts [/quote:c1891a7ad3]
outside text
[quote:c1891a7ad3="Budi"]
written by me , - budi
[/quote:c1891a7ad3]"
preg_replace($regex,"[quote=$2]$3[\quote]",$text);
```

but the result is not

```
"outside sample
    [quote:c1891a7ad3]
    text with link https://www.facebook.com/groups/35688476100/?fref=ts  [/quote:c1891a7ad3]
    outside text
    [quote="Budi"]
    written by me , - budi
    [\quote]"
```

How should the `regex` be modified to yield expected result?

Comment: Your regex does not match because you have a backslash in the input text (`[\quote:c1891a7ad3]`) and `/` in the regex pattern. Either fix the pattern or the input string. If you need to match `[/quote]` at the end of the pattern, fix the input and try [`"#\[quote:([^]]*)=([^]]*)\](.+)\[/quote:([^]]+)\]#isU"`](http://ideone.com/E9uRan) regex.

Comment: thanks its typo for "\" xD aaah thanks for helping me to fix this problem :3 emm.. whats the different between (.*) and ([^]]*) or the back quote ([^]]+) ? anyway thanks :D where do you learn the regex ? i want to know and learn as pro as you ! :D

Comment: Does my comment above solve your problem?

Comment: yes it does ! can you answer my comment ?

Comment: try this https://regex101.com/ for playing around with regex (every regex is explained in detail and you can also look at a library of standard regex's).

Comment: thaaaanks @cars10 but theres no "#" ?

Comment: The `#` is just "an arbitrary character that does not appear in the regex". In regex101.com this regex-limiting character is `/` and does not need to be entered into the regex field. Since `/` *does* appear in your regex you need to *mask* it like `\/`, see here: https://regex101.com/r/nB7iZ8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mismatch between the pattern and the actual string you test against. In the pattern, you have `/` in `[/quote]` and in the string, you have `\` (`[\quote:c1891a7ad3]`).

So, if your actual string in fact has `/`, all you need to fix is the `(.*)` part as the dot matches any character (including `]`) and thus can overmatch even with lazy matching.

So, use

```
$regex = "#\[quote:([^]]*)=([^]]*)\](.+)\[/quote:([^]]+)\]#isU";
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/E9uRan)

In this regex, I am using a negated character class `[^]]*` that matches *0 or more characters other than `]`*. It makes sure we only match text inside `[...]`. `(.*)` [matches](https://regex101.com/r/iB1hJ4/1) `c1891a7ad3]
text with link https://www.facebook.com/groups/35688476100/?fref`, so we need to restrict this somehow.

Comment: If you need advice on where to learn regular expressions, visit `[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), there is a lot of information. Also, you can find some [regex info on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), too.

Comment: got it ! but theres no explanation about "#" ? i still dont understand

Comment: This is a [regex delimiter character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) that separates the regex pattern `\[quote:([^]]*)=([^]]*)\](.+)\[/quote:([^]]+)\]` from the regex flags `isU`. There can be other delimiters, too, like `/` or `~`. In case of `#`, we need to escape `#` if we need to match it as a literal character in the pattern.

Comment: nice info :D thanks for coming and answer this problem :') aku terharu kak

Comment: Wow, Malay? "I'm overwhelmed", says Google. This is my first Malay phrase I've ever heard :).

Comment: hahaha , thanks for coming :D
i need to fix some problem with my regex code -,-